# get output from os.system-Zabbix trapper

Tags: python, python-2.7, zabbix

With this code I'm sending data to zabbix using trapper:

```
def zabbix_sender(key, output):
    server = "1.2.2.4"
    hostname = "host"
    cmd = "zabbix_sender -z " + server + " -s " + hostname + " -k " + key +\
            " -o \"" + output +"\""
    print os.system(cmd)
```

It outputs this to the screen

```
info from server: "processed: 1; failed: 0; total: 1; seconds spent: 0.000041"
sent: 1; skipped: 0; total: 1
```

I need to output above to variable so, if `failed: 1` I can create error handling.

Currently I'm getting 0 as output when calling this function:

```
r = zabbix_sender (key,"failed")
                print  r
```

output:0

Tried with subprocesses:

```
r=subprocess.check_output(zabbix_sender (key,"failed"),shell=False) 
print r
```

TypeError:None object is not iterable

Comment: You obviously need `subprocess.check_output` *instead of* `os.system`, not on the output from `os.system`.

Comment: The importance of precise error messages cannot be overstated. The spelling is "iterable" and the problem is surely that `None` is *not* iterable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value from `os.system()` is not the output from the command.  You want to use `subprocess.run()` instead.

```
from subprocess import run, PIPE

def zabbix_sender(key, output):
    server = "1.2.2.4"
    hostname = "host"
    cmd = ["zabbix_sender", "-z", server, "-s",  hostname,
        "-k", key, "-o",  output]
    result = run(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE
        universal_newlines=True, check=True)
    return result.stdout, result.stderr
```

Notice also how you don't want quoting around the option argument for `-o` when you are not using `shell=True`, and how your original function would `print` instead of `return` the result.

I speculate that the output you want is on stderr, not stdout; but I leave this up to you to establish.

If `zabbix_sender` is at all correctly implemented, it will return a non-zero exit code if it fails; you should handle this instead of examine its human-readable output.  With `check=True` an exception will be raised if the called process returns a failure status.

```
def zabbix_sender(key, output):
    server = "1.2.2.4"
    hostname = "host"
    try:
        result = run(["zabbix_sender", "-z", server, "-s", hostname,
            "-k", key, "-o", output],
            stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,
            universal_newlines=True, check=True)
         return result.stdout, result.stderr
    except CalledProcessError:
         # your zabbix error handling here
         # then probably
         return None
```

If you are stuck on Python before 3.5 you can try `subprocess.check_output` and friends.  More information at [Running Bash commands in Python](/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/51950538#51950538).

Comment: thank, i'm on python 2.7 and getting  `from subprocess import run, PIPE
ImportError: cannot import name run` also installed pip install run

Comment: Like I wrote in the last paragraph, you can use `subprocess.check_output` instead of `subprocess.run` on older Python versions. But see also update just now; you probably just want to call `subprocess.check()` and trap the exception.  The linked answer has (a lot) more details.

Comment: Also, you really should be thinking feverishly about how to migrate your code to Python 3, which is the supported and recommended version of the language.  By the original timeline, Python 2 would have been end-of-lifed last year already.  It is a zombie; you should avoid going near it if you can.

Comment: ok, switched to python 3 and now getting:`return run.stdout, run.stderr
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'stdout'`